# Eclipse Javadoc's popup font size

Tags: eclipse

I have Eclipse Juno running on my Fedora 17.

When I hover over a function / variable in Eclipse, a box pops up that contains information about that function with the font size of about 30 or 40 units. I have really searched hard to reduce the font size but I JUST CAN'T.

Why am I having this issue?

I know where font settings are for Eclipse IDE. I've changed and tested all options in there to see which might change the font, but none do.

Comment: Have you tried starting over with a new workspace?

Comment: Yeah.. It's a new workspace I just created from all my projects in another workspace.

Comment: Since you said that you've tried all the font-settings this may be in vain, but I can control this particular font's size via _Preferences -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Java -> Javadoc Display Font_. Are you sure that you've tried that one, too?

Comment: damn it was internally linked to the Dialog Box settings.. :-| Thanks, that solved the problem! Problem was that The font size is same but the font is somehow different which made it look HUGE.. I never looked at the font itself..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from @tobias_k in the comments helped me get to the correct settings for the dialog box. I'm reproducing it here for easy reference to anyone.

```
Preferences -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Java -> Javadoc Display Font
```

This should get you where you need to be. Just to clarify, that popup for documentation is considered a dialog box so it checks the dialog box font size for this.

Comment: don't forget, you need to restart Eclipse for this to take effect.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3a , no need restart.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to change the gnome theme, or whatever your shell is. I have similar problem in Ubuntu, the problem was in background of this window, it was black, and my font was black too, so nothing can be read but when i change my theme everything is fine now.